# I want to install mariadb at ubuntu 14.04 but an error occurred

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

I want to install MariaDB on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
    sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
    sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu vivid main'
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mariadb-server :
Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.7+maria-1~vivid) but it is not
going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

**`vivid`** is Vivid Vervet, that is 15.04. You're using a wrong repository that contains packages built for a newer version of Ubuntu relying on packages that have not been backported to your distro release.

What you need is 14.04 Trusty Tahr, hence **`trusty`**. [See here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=timeweb&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=trusty--ubuntu_trusty&version=10.1).

It's best you remove the repository you added accidentally and start from scratch, adding the correct one this time.

Comment: How to remove vivid repository ?? Please help me

Comment: @Arif see [this AskUbuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).

Comment: Thanks... I am trying... @D-side

Comment: follow your answer 
Also problem occurred

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.21+maria-1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @Arif I have no further information on the matter, sorry. By following the instructions I was able to install MariaDB onto a clean 14.04.